# SoundCloud created_at[from] query resolving in a 503 error

Tags: api, soundcloud

Using the JavaScript SDK, I am trying to search for all tracks in a given genre from a given date going forward (using the 'created_at[from]' /tracks filter).

My JavaScript for this is:

```
SC.get('/tracks', { genres: 'metal', created_at: {from: '2014-02-26 00:00:01'} }, function(tracks) {
  console.log(tracks);
});
```

The request URL resolves as:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?genres=metal&created_at[from]=2014-02-26%2000%3A00%3A01&client_id=MY_ID
```

and I get a 503. (I omitted posting my client_id here intentionally)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with both created_at[from] and created_at[to]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they changed the filter or its a bug or they are working on it:

When i call:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?limit=1&genres=metal&client_id=b45b1aa10f1ac2941910a7f0d10f8e28&created_at=2010-10-10
```

I am getting:

```
invalid filter.created_at=2010-10-10; 
valid values are: last_year, last_two_weeks, last_week, last_day, last_hour
```

Then, when i call for last hour:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?limit=1&genres=metal&client_id=b45b1aa10f1ac2941910a7f0d10f8e28&created_at=last_hour
```

I am getting a: 503 - Service Unavailable

When i change it to last_year, it works as expected,
and i get following xml (or json):

```
<tracks next-href="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=b45b1aa10f1ac2941910a7f0d10f8e28&created_at=last_year&genres=metal&limit=1&offset=1" type="array">
<track>
<kind>track</kind>
<id type="integer">103909859</id>
<created-at type="datetime">2013-08-04T01:30:44Z</created-at>
<user-id type="integer">29394873</user-id>
<duration type="integer">248917</duration>
<commentable type="boolean">true</commentable>
<state>finished</state>
<original-content-size type="integer">4696472</original-content-size>
<sharing>public</sharing>
<tag-list>
exotoxis metal femalevocals rock shredding army god double bass
</tag-list>
<permalink>army-of-god</permalink>
<streamable type="boolean">true</streamable>
<embeddable-by>all</embeddable-by>
<downloadable type="boolean">false</downloadable>
<purchase-url nil="true"/>
<label-id nil="true"/>
<purchase-title nil="true"/>
<genre>Metal</genre>
<title>Army Of God</title>
<description>
For more Information plea
```

EDIT:
I'd say you are right and SC Team should give an answer on that.